# Can I specify week 0 in ice_cube gem when I want to a job to run every 2 weeks?

Tags: ruby, ice-cube

I have this recurring job in our Rails service that sends out emails on Friday every two weeks. However, based on our business requirement, the first week of the "every two weeks" schedule should be this week, which means the email should be sent out this Friday, and then 2 weeks after that, and 4 weeks after that, etc.

The schedule shouldn't be broken when the service restarts. For example, after the email is sent out this Friday, if I restart the service on Saturday, it shouldn't schedule the job to Friday next week -- should still be the Friday of the week after next week. In short, the week 0 should be persistent and stick to this week.

Is it doable in ice_cube? Or are there any other better solution? Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Setting "week 0" is built into IceCube. When you create the schedule, specify the start time rather than `Time.now`.

```
2.1.4 :012 > s = IceCube::Schedule.new(Time.now.beginning_of_month)
2.1.4 :013 > s.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.monthly.count(3)
2.1.4 :014 > s.all_occurrences
 => [2014-12-01 00:00:00 -0500, 2015-01-01 00:00:00 -0500, 2015-02-01 00:00:00 -0500]
```

Here, I told IceCube the schedule starts at the beginning of this month, although I could have used any value. IceCube computes the schedule based on that time, giving me Dec 1, Jan 1, and Feb 1.